# Can't use keyword 'fixed' for a variable in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, fixed, unsafe

I tested the keyword `fixed` with array and string variables and worked really well but I can't use with a single variable.

```
static void Main() {

    int value = 12345;
    unsafe {
        fixed (int* pValue = &value) { // problem here
            *pValue = 54321;
        }
    }
}
```

The line `fixed (int* pValue = &value)` causes a complier error. I don't get it because the variable `value` is out of the `unsafe` block and it is not pinned yet.

Why can't I use `fixed` for the variable `value`?

Comment: You should be asking just one question per question, not several.  You also haven't included the actual error message for the code in question.

Comment: fixed is used to fix an array not single type.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary `fixed` has two completely orthogonal meanings in different contexts.  It's used to create arrays inline in a structure, and it's used to pin a value in memory so that it cannot be moved by the GC while its accessed in unmanaged code.

Comment: Have you tried placing `value` inside the unsafe block?

Comment: `int value = 12345;` is already fixed expression. so you just need its pointer.  `int* pointer = &value;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because `value` is a local variable, allocated on the stack, so it's already fixed. This is mentioned in the error message:

> CS0213 You cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed expression

If you need the address of `value`, you don't need the `fixed` statement, you can get it directly:

```
int* pValue = &value;
```