# Understanding unmanaged keyword in C#

Tags: c#, unmanaged, unsafe

## **Situation**

I was reading MSDN docs about what's new in C# 7.x to 8.0 and found these articles ([doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types), [doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint))

so I decided to create a little test.

## **Code**

*Pointer.cs*

```
internal readonly unsafe struct Pointer<T>
    where T : unmanaged
{
    private readonly void* mValue;

    internal Pointer(T value)
    {
        //fixed (T* val = &value) <--- Error: You cannot use the fixed statement to take the adress of an already fixed expression.
        //    mValue = val;

        mValue = &value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Pointer<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Pointer<T>(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Pointer<T> value)
    {
        var ptr = (T*)value.mValue;
        return ptr->ToString(); // returns random values (maybe adresses).
    }
}
```

*Program.cs*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pointer<int> ptr = 2;

        Console.WriteLine(ptr); // prints random values (maybe adresses).
    }
}
```

## **Problem**

why am I not allowed to use `fixed` statement in my constructor. I mean it makes sense, that it throws an error. I have said that `T` should be `unmanaged`, so I think it automatically uses `fixed` keyword internally. BUT if it does so then why am I getting random values.

Comment: According to [CS0213](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0213) error, your `value` variable is already fixed in the stack. This question [Can't use keyword 'fixed' for a variable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384525/cant-use-keyword-fixed-for-a-variable-in-c-sharp) tells the same

Comment: Which output do you expect, why just don't use `ToString()` method directly, without operator overload

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski You are correct, however this isn't a production code, I just wanted to test the 'casting' operators...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation for unmanaged types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types) T will be some kind of value type that cannot contain references to managed types. As such it will be allocated on the stack. When the constructor returns the stack will be popped and the pointer will be pointing to some undefined value. You cannot use `fixed` for something allocated on the stack since cannot be moved by the garbage collector anyway, and is therefore considered 'fixed'.

Comment: Good to know, but does it explain why am I getting random values at the end? (Unless I'm missing something)

Comment: You are getting random values since it will point to whatever data happens to be stored at that address. This would not be actualy random, but it might as well be that. In short, you should never do this. you should always ensure the data a pointer points to has a longer lifetime than the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of what is happening:

1. Here you get a by value copy of the `int` in the stack.

   ```
   internal Pointer(T value)
   ```
2. Here you take a pointer to the `int` in the stack.

   ```
   mValue = &value;
   ```
3. Then the constructor finishes, and the int is pop'd from the stack, the pointer is orphan.
4. Something else is put on the stack, such as the `Pointer<T>` struct itself, the pointer now leads to garbage.

   ```
   public static implicit operator string(Pointer<T> value)
   ```
5. You read the garbage as an `int`.

   ```
   var ptr = (T*)value.mValue;
   ```

Comment: What do You think is there any solution/workaround to this problem? Or is this normal behavior?

Comment: @Hrant it is expected that you get garbage with something like this. As per workarounds,  `Span<T>` I guess? I don't know what is the best approach for this in C#. I'd say avoid pointers, use ref. Addendum: you need to ensure that whatever you point to is alive and fixed. Consider also `StrongBox<T>`.